# I want to open a dynamic page using JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I am creating a dynamic page in html using JavaScript using an array. Now I want to add a functionality where, once I click the blog post, it takes me to a new dynamic page which should contain the children of that particular array. Is it possible?

How the dynamic page will be created as well as how will it show the exact targeted array item I want to display on the page and also how it will iterate using that array. There are many sort of questions in my mind. Also, does it make the rendering faster or help improving the website speed?

Here's the code for your reference. Any help will be appreciated as I have been through various documentations, videos, etc. but there hasn't been something relevant.

It's a blog post website where we can create and display blogs dynamically.

```
<section class="mainsection darkbg">
  <h1 class="somewhatlargefont width100 margintop20 accentfont mainfont">Our Blog</h1>
  <div class="blogrow margintop20" id="servicelist">
  </div>
</section>
```

Here's the array I am using:

```
let dataarr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: "images/analysis.jpg",
    date: "16/10/2023",
    createdby: "Atin pal",
    blogname: "How IT is changing the world",
    blogdetails:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam neque, eum rem saepe, suscipit natus nisi optio voluptates beatae necessitatibus excepturi incidunt delectus dolores. Id neque in ex blanditiis, inventore fugit modi voluptatum ipsam error ut iste adipisci maiores soluta qui repudiandae excepturi mollitia officiis reiciendis incidunt nam distinctio fuga.",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    img: "images/analysis.jpg",
    date: "16/10/2023",
    createdby: "Atin pal",
    blogname: "How IT is changing the world",
    blogdetails:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam neque, eum rem saepe, suscipit natus nisi optio voluptates beatae necessitatibus excepturi incidunt delectus dolores. Id neque in ex blanditiis, inventore fugit modi voluptatum ipsam error ut iste adipisci maiores soluta qui repudiandae excepturi mollitia officiis reiciendis incidunt nam distinctio fuga.",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    img: "images/analysis.jpg",
    date: "16/10/2023",
    createdby: "Atin pal",
    blogname: "How IT is changing the world",
    blogdetails:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam neque, eum rem saepe, suscipit natus nisi optio voluptates beatae necessitatibus excepturi incidunt delectus dolores. Id neque in ex blanditiis, inventore fugit modi voluptatum ipsam error ut iste adipisci maiores soluta qui repudiandae excepturi mollitia officiis reiciendis incidunt nam distinctio fuga.",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    img: "images/analysis.jpg",
    date: "16/10/2023",
    createdby: "Atin pal",
    blogname: "How IT is changing the world",
    blogdetails:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam neque, eum rem saepe, suscipit natus nisi optio voluptates beatae necessitatibus excepturi incidunt delectus dolores. Id neque in ex blanditiis, inventore fugit modi voluptatum ipsam error ut iste adipisci maiores soluta qui repudiandae excepturi mollitia officiis reiciendis incidunt nam distinctio fuga.",
  },
];
```

Here's the JavaScript code:

```
let services = document.getElementById("servicelist");

dataarr.forEach((list) => {
  const maindiv = document.createElement("div");
  const blogimg = document.createElement("img");
  const secondarydiv = document.createElement("div");
  const serviceTitle = document.createElement("h1");
  const serviceDet = document.createElement("p");
  const readmorecont = document.createElement("div");
  const readmoretxt = document.createElement("p");

  services.append(maindiv);
  maindiv.append(secondarydiv);
  secondarydiv.append(serviceTitle);
  secondarydiv.append(serviceDet);
  maindiv.append(readmorecont);
  readmorecont.append(readmoretxt);
  serviceTitle.innerHTML = list.blogname;
  serviceDet.innerHTML = list.blogdetails;
  readmoretxt.innerHTML = "Read More";
  maindiv.setAttribute("class", "servicecard shadowed");
  blogimg.setAttribute("class", "blogimg");
  serviceDet.setAttribute("class", "centertext, iconlight");
  readmorecont.setAttribute("class", "buttonmain width100");
  secondarydiv.setAttribute("class", "blogsecondarydiv");
  serviceDet.setAttribute("class", "margintop20");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the straightforwad solution id to use url params, you can change each blog div to a link

instead of this: `const maindiv = document.createElement("div");` change it to something like `const maindiv = document.createElement("a");`

and after this line: `const readmoretxt = document.createElement("p");`

you can create new variable for link url e.g.

`const pageLink = http://example.com/blog.html?blogName=${list.blogname}&blogDetails=${list.blogdetails} ... and so on`

and in the blog.html file you can get these url params and display them.

Comment: I understood it, Thank you so much, but can I get a little more reference on the same?